# Configure premake script directories and libraries depending on platform toolset

Tags: premake

I'm trying to convert my visual studio project files to use premake to generate solutions for different visual studio versions.

I would like to write configuration functions for each of the libraries so that it will set different include directory, library directory, and dlls depending on the platform toolset. I have tried using the configuration or filter command but this is not working and is including all the libraries and directories to my project instead.

A simplified example of what i'm trying to do is below.

```
function projectconfig()    
    filename "MyProj" 
    kind "SharedLib"
    language "C++"         
    filter "action:vs2010"
         links "lib_vc100"
         ..etc
    filter "action:vs2012"
        links "lib_vc110"
        ..etc
    filter {} <--- This had to be added to fix the issue
end
```

How should I go about doing something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: That is exactly how you would go about doing it; there must be something else wrong. What are getting when you run that script?

Comment: I have since solved this issue by doing as above but adding a filter {} at the end to reset it after the end of the function.  I believe without "filter {}" at the end it was not including all the libraries.  Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my code above with the fix i made.  My solution file contains many projects calling similar functions set up as above.  without adding "filter {} " the dependencies were getting mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

if this is not working you could work around it by using

```
if _ACTION == "vs2010" then
```

end

but please consider filing a bug with this !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VS macros in premake:

```
libdirs "libs/$(PlatformToolset)"
links "foo"
```

Then in your source tree:

```
libs/
    v110/
        foo.lib
    v120/
        foo.lib
    v140/
        foo.lib
```